# Erro no GDI+ ao selectionar a frame ativa

Tags: c#, listview, processamento-de-imagens

Estou com um problema quando tento dividir ficheiros multi page TIFF.

À medida que vou dividindo os ficheiros, guardo cada página numa pasta temporária e guardo um JPG desse TIFF para utilizá-lo como thumbnail da imagem no `ListView`. 
Ou seja, guardo cada página do TIFF na pasta temporária, para cada página nessa pasta irei guardar a thumbnail numa pasta chamada "Thumbnails" e apresentar tudo no ListView.

O meu problema é que quando divido o TIFF, a primeira página funciona bem e quando vai fazer a 2ª página, dá esse erro:

[image: Erro]

O meu código é este aqui:

```
string pastapdf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + name;
Directory.CreateDirectory(pastapdf);

for (int index = 0; index < pages; index++) //aqui funciona tudo bem
{
    activePage = index + 1;                           
    image.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, index);
    image.Save(pastapdf + "\\" + name + " -Pagina " + activePage + ".tif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
}

string[] tiffiles = GetFiles(pastapdf, "*.tif"); //vou buscar os ficheiros TIFF
for(int idx = 0; idx < tiffiles.Length; idx++)
{
    activePage = idx + 1;
    using (System.Drawing.Image image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tiffiles[idx]))
    {

        image2.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, idx);//<-- erro aqui 
        image2.Save(thumbnail + "\\" + name + " -Pagina " + activePage + "_thumbnail" + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
        thumbnails.Images.Add(h.ToString(), image2);
        image2.Dispose();
    }

    string fich = pastapdf + "\\" + name + " -Pagina " + activePage + ".tif";
    //aqui crio o item novo no ListView
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fich);
    ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
    _item1.ImageKey = h.ToString();
    _item1.Text = name + " -Pagina " + activePage + ".tif";
    _item1.SubItems.Add(f.Length.ToString());

    lista4.Items.Add(_item1);
    h++;
}
```

Comment: Onde, no código, estoura o erro?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Eu identifiquei a linha, é onde faço "image2.SelectActiveFrame()".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi o problema e era um erro meu.

Sendo que eu já tinha separado o ficheiro TIFF antes e só estava a ir buscar as páginas 1 a 1, não podia seleccionar nenhuma ActiveFrame pois as páginas já estavam separadas e cada uma tinha apenas 1 frame.

Concluindo, basta retirar a linha:

```
image2.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Page, idx);
```

E fica tudo a funcionar corretamente sem erros, sendo que os ficheiros já foram separados antes!